# IIS 7.5 Web Server Farm with separate domain accounts

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, web-farm

We have 4 servers running Server 2008 R2 x64 with IIS 7.5 and they're linked together with a Web Server Farm. Content is being distributed to each server correctly and also websites so when it comes to replication nothing is required at this point.

My problem is that previously we had 1 domain account to access a centralized folder (which will now be sitting in the WWWroot folder to copy content across the other servers as well) and I want to create a separate account for each server rather than a generic one, so in case 1 fails, it won't affect all servers just 1.

Where can I specify in the apphostconfig file that each domain account needs to access this folder only on a specific server? I don't want to break the farm since it's working properly and therefore I don't want to experiment.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible as the Web Farm Framework will attempt to replicate ALL settings including ACLs from the master server to the secondaries.  What kinds of failures would you have with a generic service account for a .NET application pool?

It seems like you would normally set it and forget it with a domain account.

Comment: Thanks Brent for your feedback.  The problem is that these servers are being load-balanced physically as opposed to using ARR from Web Farms so in case 1 of the accounts get locked out, that server will be detached from the load-balancer pool.

Comment: Like I said, you can't have multiple accounts setup as far as I know because every time the web farm sync runs it will replace the assigned user account.  We used NLB with our farm and like you point out if a server goes down there is really no way to handle that error.  You would have to have some sort of a response or timeout period setup on your LB to handle proper failover.

Comment: Not even the following link can be of any help? http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1301/changing-authentication-mode-for-a-given-website/

Comment: No as that pertains to the actual ASP.NET membership and authentication modules and has nothing to do with the application pool that IIS is executing the process under.

Answer (score -1):

in that case you need to follow shared network content infrastructure.

Shared configuration is an IIS feature that helps support homogeneous web farms where all web servers share the same configuration. By using a UNC share, any changes to a master configuration file propagate across different servers without extra tools or programmatic support.

You enable shared configuration in two steps by using the IIS Manager.
Export the configuration files to a shared folder on the back-end file server.
Point IIS to the UNC path for that shared folder.

at this point you can specify windows authentication account to access shared information with all web servers.

Comment: He is already using the Web Farm Framework which is far more powerful than the standard shared network content infrastructure.  Even with this you can only configure a single account to use on ALL servers, not individual.